# А можно упростить XML файл конфигураци Spring?

Tags: java, xml, spring

Ну я сразу скажу, что только начинаю изучать Spring, так что не судите очень строго.
Поймал себя на том, что пишу в файле конфигурации одно и то же.

```
<bean id="sorttask"
        class="Arhitecture.Sort.Sort_Task"
        factory-method="getTaskInstance" />

<bean id="timer"
      class="Arhitecture.ClockWork"
      scope="prototype"/>



<bean id="bubblesort"
      class="Solutions.Bubble_Sort">
    <constructor-arg ref="sorttask"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bubbleclock"
      class="Arhitecture.ClockWork"/>

<bean id="bubblesortwrapper"
      class="Arhitecture.Sort.Sort_SolutionWrapper">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="bubblesort"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="bubbleclock"/>
</bean>

<!--Feel like doing the same thing-->
<!--Need to find a way like <context:component-scan> and for each solution bean do new wrapper (solution, timer) -->


<bean id="mergesort"
      class="Solutions.Sort_by_Merge">>
    <constructor-arg ref="sorttask"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mergeclock"
      class="Arhitecture.ClockWork"/>
<bean id="mergesortwrapper"
      class="Arhitecture.Sort.Sort_SolutionWrapper">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="mergesort"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="mergeclock"/>
</bean>




<aop:config>
     <aop:pointcut id="runBubble" expression="execution(* Solutions.Bubble_Sort.run(..))"/>
     <aop:aspect ref="bubbleclock">
         <aop:before pointcut-ref="runBubble" method="clockStart"/>
         <aop:after  pointcut-ref="runBubble" method="clockEnd"/>
     </aop:aspect>

    <aop:aspect ref="bubblesortwrapper">
        <aop:after pointcut-ref="runBubble" method="setCorrectness"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

В конфигурации аспекта придется добавлять те же строки для других id.
**Чтобы не повторяться, в голову приходит использовать `<context:component-scan base-package="Solutions"/>`, но я не придумал как создать для каждого отсканеного bean новый wrapper.**
*Подскажите, пожалуйста где искать решение.*
Потом можно получить ссылки на все компоненты класса SolutionWrapper из объекта контекста, это я разобрался как сделать.

Comment: а почему аннотации не используете?

Comment: Потому, что никто меня об этом раньше не спросил и я закончил 4-ю главу книги Spring in Action на этих выходных читать. Можно поподробнее?

Comment: вместо xml можно использовать аннотации, java-классы или groovy. или можно все это смешать. но я не рекомендую. обсуждение в комментариях на СО не рекомендуется. задайте вопрос и вам на него ответят.

Comment: Про аннотации прочитал. Интересно. Я так понял, это сделано чтобы сократить размер файла конфигурации. Пока меня размер устраивает. Сейчас планирую разобраться как это все работает. И повторю вопрос. Как автоматически создать для каждого автоматически задетектенного бина бин класса "Arhitecture.Sort.Sort_SolutionWrapper", как в конструктор передать новый ClockWork я разобрался (bean id = timer)

Comment: СО - это не форум.